# A proof that $\langle u,v\mid u^4=v^3=1, uv=v^2u^2\rangle$ defines the trivial group.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

[This appears to be new to MSE.](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%2C%20%24%5Clangle%5C%20u%2Cv%5C%20%5Cmid%5C%20u%5E4%3Dv%5E3%3D1%2C%5C%20uv%3Dv%5E2u%5E2%5Crangle%5C%20%24&p=1)

I'm reading *"Abstract Algebra (Third Edition),"* by Dummit & Foote.

This is based on Exercise 1.2.18.

> **Question:** Show that $$Y=\langle u,v\mid u^4=v^3=1, uv=v^2u^2\rangle$$ is defines the trivial group.

### My Attempt:

**Tietze transformations are not yet introduced in the text and so they do not apply here.**

From $v^3=1$ and $u^4=1$, we have $v^2=v^{-1}$ and $u^3=u^{-1}$, respectively. Also $u^{-2}=u^2$.

Also, we have

\begin{align}
\color{red}{v^2u^3v}
&=(v^2u^2)(uv) \\
&=v^2u^{-1}v \\
&=v^{-1}u^{-1}v \\
&=(uv)^{-1}v \\
&=(v^2u^2)^{-1}v \\
&=u^{-2}v^{-2}v \\
&=\color{red}{u^3v},^\dagger
\end{align}

so that $v^2=1$. Now $v^2=v^{-1}$ implies $v=1$.

Thus we can kill $v$:

$$Y=\langle u\mid u^4=1, u=u^2\rangle,$$

but now $u=u^2$ implies $u=1$.

Hence the group given by $Y$ is trivial as all its generators are trivial. $\square$

---

My problem is that the proof Exercise 1.2.18 *ibid.* guides the reader through a different path.

Thus I would like to know if my proof holds.

The only thing that I stumble on in the proof outlined in the exercise is part (b), which gets the reader to show, in effect, that

$$v^2u^3v=u^3.$$

This ought to be simple for me but I just don't see it. The rest of the exercise seems easy.

> Why do I get an extra $v$ in the RHS?

---

$\dagger$ I've just noticed that a $u$ comes from nowhere in this step. Sorry!

Comment: I don't see how you go from $u^{-2}v^{-2}v$ to $u^3v$. $u^{-2} = u^2$ and $v^{-2}v = v^{-1} = v^2$.

Comment: The first one is wrong; see the $\dagger$ footnote. For the second one, $u^4=1$. I don't think I used the last one, @jsmith.

Comment: Hang on, @jsmith: for the last one, $v^3=1$, so that $v^{-3}=1$. Recall that $$v^{-k}=(v^{-1})^k.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}uv^2 &= v^2u^2v\\
&= v^2u(uv)=v^2uv^2u^2\\
&= v^2(uv)vu^2=vu^2vu^2\\
&= vu(uv)u^2=vuv^2\\
&= v(uv)v=u^2v\end{align*} Hence $u=v$; since $u^4=1=v^3=u^3$, $u=v=1$.

Answer (score 1):

> ... part (b), which gets the reader to show, in effect, that
> $$v^2u^3v=u^3.$$
> This ought to be simple for me but I just don't see it. The rest of the exercise seems easy.

Yeah somehow I didn't see this at first either.

But believe the idea is to start with the LHS. Then apply the relation $u v = v^2 u^2$, once in each direction.
\begin{align}
v^2 u^3 v
&= (v^2 u^2) (u v) \\
&= (u v) (u v) \\
&= (u v) (v^2 u^2) \\
&= u v^3 u^2 \\
&= u^3.
\end{align}